# pandas 0.23.1 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rolling'

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import *

print (pd.__version__)
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1':['a','a','b','b','a'],
               'key2':['one','two','one','two','one'],
               'data1':np.nan,
               'data2':np.random.randn(5)})

df = pd.rolling(df[['data1','data2']],window = 3)
print (df)
```

return:

```
0.23.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jj.py", line 33, in <module>
    df = pd.rolling(df[['data1','data2']],window = 3)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rolling'
```

I try python2 and python3 at my computer, but all failed when I use rolling()

Comment: Use `df[['data1','data2']].rolling(window=3)` or `df[['data1','data2']].rolling(window=3).sum()`

Comment: it works, think you very match!

Answer (score 2):

the `pandas` module itself has no method `rolling`. You should call it as a method of the instanced `DataFrame` class, something like

```
df[['data1','data2']].rolling(window=3)
```